# Add whitespace / increase the space between the X and the Y axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

I am doing some plots for a project where they need to have a specific look. They will need to have some space between the axes lines and the plot panel.

```
library(ggplot2)

plot_data <- data.frame(X = 1:10, Y = 1:10)

ggplot() + geom_point(data = plot_data, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", linetype = "solid"))
```

What I have

[image: What I have]

I want to add some distance between the X and Y axis of my plot, but without my axes lines also expanding, like they if I use the expand command.

```
plot_data <- data.frame(X = 1:10, Y = 1:10)


ggplot() + geom_point(data = plot_data, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", linetype = "solid"))+
scale_x_continuous(name = "X", limits = c(1, 10),  expand = c(0.1,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Y", limits = c(1, 10),  expand = c(0.1,0))
```

What I can do
[image: What I can do]

Is there a fast and reliable way to do this in R?

What i want
[image: What i want]

Thank you all in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this "capping" of the lines with the `lemon` package. You may use the following code to achieve this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lemon)

### your code
plot_data <- data.frame(X = 1:10, Y = 1:10)

p <- ggplot() + geom_point(data = plot_data, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", linetype = "solid"))+
  scale_x_continuous(name = "X", limits = c(1, 10),  expand = c(0.1,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Y", limits = c(1, 10),  expand = c(0.1,0))

### using the lemon package
p + coord_capped_cart(bottom='right', left='none', gap = 0.15)

### mimic the view of your plot
p2 <- p + coord_capped_cart(bottom='right', left='none', gap = 0.15)
p2 + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

which yields the following picture:

[image]

Comment: Thats perfect. Thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

An other option : Deleting the axis lines and making new ones with geom_segment.

```
plot_data <- data.frame(X = 1:10, Y = 1:10)

library(ggplot2)



ggplot() + geom_point(data = plot_data, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
    theme(axis.line = element_blank(),panel.background =element_blank())+
  geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=1,xend=0,yend=10))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=1,y=0,xend=10,yend=0))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c(1,2,3,4,5, 8,10))+
  scale_y_discrete(limits=c(1:10))
```

[image]